# PrintJob TimeSubmitted how to cast to datetime

Tags: c#, printing

I have a C# class that takes job printers and some of its properties including TimeSubmitted, that is stored as DateTime with this format: 20130608204517.699000-300

I defined an object with this properties:

```
public class PrinterJob
{
    public String Document { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public UInt32 JobId { get; set; }
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    //===========================================================================
    // This property doesn't cast adecuate 
    //===========================================================================
    public Datetime TimeSubmitted { get; set; }
}
```

When I'll try to cast the DateTime (at Run Time):

```
foreach (ManagementObject prntJob in prntJobCollection)
{
    System.String jobName = prntJob.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();

    //Job name would be of the format [Printer name], [Job ID]
    char[] splitArr = new char[1];
    splitArr[0] = Convert.ToChar(",");
    string prnterName = jobName.Split(splitArr)[0];
    if (String.Compare(prnterName, printerName, true) == 0)
    {
        PrinterJob prtobj = new PrinterJob();
        prtobj.Document = prntJob.Properties["Document"].Value.ToString();
        prtobj.JobName = prntJob.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
        var id = prntJob.Properties["JobId"].Value;
        prtobj.JobId = (UInt32)prntJob.Properties["JobId"].Value;
        prtobj.JobStatus = prntJob.Properties["JobStatus"].Value.ToString();
        //============================================================================  
        // Here The cast doesn't work. It comes as: 20130608204517.699000-300 
        // It throws an InvalidCastException
        //============================================================================  
        prtobj.TimeSubmitted = (DateTime)prntJob.Properties["TimeSubmitted"].Value;
        jobList.Add(prtobj);
    }
}
```

What is the right way to cast this value to convert it to DateTime?

Comment: why don't just use `DateTime.ParseExact("20130608204517.699000-300".Split('.')[0], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);`?

Comment: It Works fine, but What if need more precisión beyond seconds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add reference to `System.Management`

```
var datetime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime("20130608204517.699000-300");
```

- [**`ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime.aspx)

Comment: Excelent, It Works fine, but it only cast until seconds, how can i do to get milliseconds ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez how many milliseconds you expected? have you check `datetime.Millisecond` property?

Comment: at least 3 decimals. It Works excelent. Just another question, milliseconds are taken if use Linq Query to order the Jobs ?

Comment: you can use `Ticks` property of date time object, if you convert and compare `"20130608204517.699000-300"`.`"20130608204517.699001-300"` you will see the accuracy of this conversion

Comment: Excelent, very tks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt that a simple datetime? (ie. yyyyMMddHHmmss)
I wouldnt know what the part after the dot means though.

Comment: Yes it is the date in yyyyMMddHHmmss